# Is there any explanation as to why there is a rocket in the Village?

Tags: the-prisoner

In the final episode of The Prisoner ("Fall Out"), as Number 6 is led to Number 1, he finds himself inside a rocket (re-used sets from "The Girl Who Was Death"). There is no on-screen explanation of why there was a rocket there, or what it was for (unless you interpret the children's bedtime story to be a form of foreshadowing). Was there ever any ["Word of God"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WordOfGod) explanation for it? The whole episode is rather surreal and incongruous; is that just more incongruity to accept as-is - kinda like some of the bizarre happenings in [Casino Royale (1967)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casino_Royale_(1967_film))?

Comment: The most famously inexplicable episode of one of the most inexplicable TV shows of all time, and you're worried about why the 60s island of super-spy mystery has a rocket?

Comment: I suggest watching or read transcript of the Warner Troyer prisoner interview of Patrick McGoohan for the word of God on the Prisoner in general - i don't recall if this was specifically addressed.  My own comment on why in-universe is it's the same reason there are missle silos in Iowa farm fields (or wherever they are).  Atomic deterrence against the other side.  Atomic bombs are very prevalent in the entertainment of the time see also Planet of the Apes...or beneath it. Or several James Bond films.

Comment: I feel that expecting an explanation of *anything* from The Prisoner is being very hopeful.

Comment: There's a rocket in the village specifically to inspire questions like the one being asked above.